# How do I change the language/locale in the Google Assistant SDK?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

As of the [Google Assistant SDK 0.4.1](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/the-google-assistant-sdk-new-languages.html), developers using it can change the language/locale using both the Google Assistant Library and the Google Assistant Service.

This post will explain how developers can take advantage of this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Google Assistant Service

Using the gRPC API, developers can easily and programmatically change the locale in each API call. They can also change the locale as an argument to the `pushtotalk.py` sample.

We can take a look at [the Embedded Assistant protobuf](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/assistant/embedded/v1alpha2/embedded_assistant.proto) which shows the API.

#### Embedded Assistant Protobuf

```
rpc Assist(stream AssistRequest) returns (stream AssistResponse);
```

The API call requires an `AssistantRequest` and returns an `AssistResponse`

An [`AssistantRequest`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/assistant/embedded/v1alpha2/embedded_assistant.proto#L251) can be an [`AssistConfig`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/assistant/embedded/v1alpha2/embedded_assistant.proto#L77). An `AssistConfig` may contain several properties including a [`DialogStateIn`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/assistant/embedded/v1alpha2/embedded_assistant.proto#L169). A `DialogStateIn` may contain several properties including a [`language_code`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/assistant/embedded/v1alpha2/embedded_assistant.proto#L183).

```
string language_code = 2;
```

From the documentation about this property:

```
// *Required* Language of the request in
// [IETF BCP 47 syntax](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47). For example:
// "en-US". If you have selected a language for this `device_id` using the
// [Settings](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/assistant-settings)
// menu in your phone's Google Assistant app, that selection will override
// this value.
```

Using strings such as **en-US**, **fr-FR** or any other locale that the Assistant supports.

#### `pushtotalk.py`

Developers running the sample can change locales by including the [`--lang`](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/blob/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/pushtotalk.py#L235) argument followed by the locale code when running the script.

#### Google Assistant settings

After you [register your device](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/register-device) it will appear in the list of devices in the Google Assistant settings.

Google Assistant > Explore > Settings > Devices

From here, you can go into settings for each device. This will allow you to change the language of the device using a friendly picker. Note that once you do, this will override the value set programmatically.

[image: Google Assistant settings]

## Google Assistant Library

If you are using the Google Assistant Library or the `hotword.py` sample, you can only change the language in the Google Assistant settings on your phone.

Comment: What device type did you register your assistant as? None of the options seem to fit.

Comment: The type is not too important. Using action.devices.types.LIGHT is sufficient. The traits are more important to include if you want to use device actions.